# How to create manual inputs in CakePHP 2 using SecurityComponent?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I want to create a form in CakePHP whilst having the `SecurityComponent` active. So far so good, now I want to add custom `input` elements which I can't generate using the `FormHelper`. I do however to have these fields included in the security and validation checks.

The main problem is that I can't render radio buttons outside of their labels. So I render them myself like so:

```
<div class="radio radio-inline">
    <input id="genderMALE" type="radio" name="data[User][gender]" value="MALE"/>
    <label for="genderMALE">Male</label>
</div>
<div class="radio radio-inline">
    <input id="genderFEMALE" type="radio" name="data[User][gender]" value="FEMALE"/>
    <label for="genderFEMALE">Female</label>
</div>
```

Which in itself works perfectly. Yet the `FormHelper` has no notice of them so the `SecurityComponent` registers this as tampering with the form. Blackholing my request.

I tried to generate the inputs using the `FormHelper` but radio support is limited. The `format` option does not work here since:

> Radio buttons cannot have the order of input and label elements controlled with these settings.
>   -- [Cookbook](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-FormHelper.html#_input)

Next to that I couldn't find any way to render a plain detached radio button. And the only way I found to have the `input` accepted was through ignoring it in the `SecurityComponent`.

What is the Cake way to fix this?

**Update 14-09 09:16**
My current fix/hack would be to create the custom radio buttons in plain HTML as shown above. Then link the value of those radio inputs to an input field created using the `FormHelper`. Using CSS I can hide this input allowing it to be changed by JavaScript, as opposed to using `type="hidden"`.

Are there any dangers/problems that could occur using this method?

*side note: In the end this is a styling issue. Yet I'm forced to use Bootstrap and have only 2 days left to finish my task. And I don't feel like going down the path of writing custom CSS/JS to get this working.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point of getting content with the hack solution, I stumbled upon the `FormHelper::$fields` field. This field keeps track of all inputs created using the `FormHelper` and is later used by the `SecurityComponent` to check whether the form has been tampered with.

The solution does require some additional work as you need to implement the following steps:

1. Add custom form element the the `fields` array
2. Restore value from previous submit (if redirect back to form)
3. Add default option so field won't be omitted from post data

Working CTP

```
<div class="radio radio-inline">
    <input id="genderMALE" type="radio" name="data[User][gender]" value="MALE" 
        <?= $this->request->data('User.gender') == 'MALE' ? 'checked' : ''?> />
    <label for="genderMALE">Male</label>
</div>
<div class="radio radio-inline">
    <input id="genderFEMALE" type="radio" name="data[User][gender]" value="FEMALE" 
        <?= $this->request->data('User.gender') == 'FEMALE' ? 'checked' : ''?> />
    <label for="genderFEMALE">Female</label>
</div>
<input type="radio" name="data[User][gender]" value="" class="hidden" 
   <?= $this->request->data('User.gender') ? '' : 'checked'?> />
<?php $this->Form->fields[] = 'User.gender' ?>
```

It is far from pretty, yet I recon it is close to the internals of Cake itself. Might want to create a helper instead of manually implementing the inputs every time.